# An algorithm problem about gene sequencing analysis

Tags: algorithm

I have an algorithm problem that I want to help you with:

Given the sequence s [0, - n-1] taken from the symbol in character table Z, that is, for 0 ≤ I ≤ n-1, s [i] ∈ Z.
Design the data structure and algorithm, use the smallest space as possible, calculate the number of times the symbol C ∈ Z appears in s [0, i] in O (log K) time, where k is the size of character table Z.
The problem requires to use the given test sequence to test, and give the actual running time and occupied space.

Further explanation:

1. The length of test sequence s is about 10 ^ 8 length, and the maximum size of Z should be the size of the ASCII table.
2. The problem requires to solve the number of a character in s [0, i], where i is unknown, implying that the question is used to query many times after constructing.
3. O (log K) time refers to the time of the query, excluding the time of data structure construction.
4. The figure below shows the distribution of characters in the test sequence s. The characters are disordered and random, but the distribution is very uneven. AGCT accounts for almost all of them, but there are some other characters. \n is a newline character, and its number can not be calculated.

My question is: obviously, the dumbest way is to traverse the s once, while building a structure similar to a two-dimensional array, storing the answer for each character in each position. But I feel so stupid Moreover, the time complexity is constant and log is not even necessary.

What I can only think of about log is binary search, however, the maximum size of Z should be the size of the ASCII table. In my opinion, it is not necessary to use binary search.

In addition, a guy proposed to store the location of each character, and then use binary search to check the number of occurrences. However, the complexity is logn, not the logK required by the problem.

Can somebody provide a more space-saving method in line with the problem, thank you

[the distribution of characters in the test sequence s](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yZ8E8.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this using a hybrid of the two approaches you're already discovered.

Divide s into blocks of O(|Z|) characters, and for each block, for each character, record the number of its occurrences *before* the block, and the positions of its occurrences *within* the block.

Now to determine the number of, say, Gs in s[0,i], you look up the last block that starts before position i, read the number of occurrences in preceding blocks, and binary search in the G positions to find how many additional positions appear before i.

The division into blocks changes the asymptotic space required from O(N*|Z|) to O(N) (assuming a constant size for counts).  In practical terms, if you use blocks of size B, then you'll spend about n * ( log(n) * |Z|/B + log(B) ) bits.

That is minimized when B=log(n) * |Z|, leading to total space n(1 + log(|Z|) + log(log(n))) bits, which you can compare to the n*log(|Z|) bits required for storing just the original sequence in a bit-packed format.  Not too bad.

If you don't want to be so careful then just make your block size 32|Z| and use 32-bit counts, which cost you about 6 bits more per character than just storing the sequence.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I think the idea of dividing sequence s into blocks is very good. But I don't understand something. When analyzing the space consumption, I don't know how "n * (log (n) * | z/ B + log (b)) bits"come from. In addition, you say N * log (| Z |) bits required for storing just the original sequence, isn't N? Because each letter takes up one byte. How can it have anything to do with log(|Z|) when considering space occupied by original sequence? Looking forward to your reply. Thank you

Comment: Each letter takes one byte if |Z| is 256. If |Z| was 4, for example, then you could store the sequence using 2 bits per letter, with 4 letters in each byte.  n * log(n) * |Z|/B is n/B blocks times |Z| counts times log(N) bits per count.  n*log(B) is n letter positions within a block times log(B) bits per position.